# flask wtforms populating drop down list

Tags: python, json, flask, wtforms

this isn't a very specific question, so sorry in advance.

I have a folder called Crews, and it contains json files.

I'm using WTForms to create a drop down list, and I want the list to be populated with the names of the json files within that folder, but I don't know how to go about this.

(I'm creating a web app that visualizes the chosen json data, so the form will contain a function that returns the chosen json data, which is called by the d3.js code)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this to get all the files in your directory:

[How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python)

Once you get that list of json files, you can use it to populate the **choices** in a WTForms [SelectField](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField)

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import SelectField

filenames = ['1.json', '2.json'] # This will be generated by you
class MyForm
    json_file = SelectField(u"Filename", [Optional()], choices=[(f, f) for f in filenames])
```

Comment: I upvoted you, but what is the '[Optional()]' parameter?

Comment: Should have post url reference to WTForms!

Comment: Very late to the party but Optional()  is a validator, that keeps the selection of the tag optional